# Android: change language from english to hindi and telugu

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to Android.

I have chosen spinner for ListView. Now I want to change language of my application as per selection from list. Here spinner contains English, Hindi and Telugu languages.Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define multiple language string file in language specific values folder.
Please refer [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

If you want to change the language by your app. Then you need to write code for.->

```
String languageToLoad  = "fa"; // your language code
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

You can find more description about it [here](http://www.danielespinetti.it/2012/03/resources-based-on-localization.html)